# How to adapt Pattern.web Google API to search single URL and return total results-count

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is adapted from an example program and it works, but I need to modify it to:

1. Search within a single URL (en.wikipedia.org)
2. Return a total results-count and load that into a variable.

   ```
   from pattern.web import Google, plaintext
   from pattern.web import SEARCH
   engine = Google(license=None, language="en")

   q = "\"cat's\""

   for i in range(1, 2):

       for result in engine.search(q, start=i, count=10, type=SEARCH, cached=True):
           print plaintext(result.text)
           print result.url
           print result.date
           print
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom license, and set the url to search in the Google dashboard.